# Simultaneous diagonalization in Matlab

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues, eigenvector

Crossposted [from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62583210/12820864). The generalised diagonalization of two matrices $A$ and $B$ can be done in Matlab via

```
[V,D] = eig(A,B);
```

where the columns of $V$ are are the generalised eigenvectors of the pair ($A$, $B$), while $D$ is a diagonal matrix containing the corresponding generalised eigenvalues.

First, is it correct to assume that the generalised eigenvectors $V$ are also simultaneous eigenvectors of both $A$ and $B$, under the assumption that $A$ and $B$ commute?

If so, I could compute the respective eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ (in the same order as the eigenvectors in $V$) as follows

```
eigA = V\A*V;
eigB = V\B*V;
```

However, is there a simpler way to achieve this, i.e. without having to compute the inverse of $V$ as in the snippet above?

Comment: if you know an eigenvector $v$ of $A$, can't you just find the corresponding eigenvalue by calculating $w=Av$ and comparing the first component of $w$ and $v$?

Comment: Thank you. This is OK except that $v(1)$ might be zero or close to zero, which makes the computation unstable. One might fix that by comparing the whole $v$ and $w$.

Comment: I think your premise is wrong; `[V,D] = diag(A, B)` does not, in general, simultaneously diagonalize matrices. It works only in sufficiently simple cases without repeated eigenvalues (try `rng(0); V = randn(5); A = V*blkdiag(1,1,3,3,3)/V; B = V * blkdiag(1,1,1,3,3)/V;`). As a workaround with possibly bad stability, try `[V, D] = eig(randn*A + randn*B)`.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Thank you very much, excellent counterexample. In my case, $A$ and $B$ were symmetric, positive definite, tridiagonal Toeplitz matrices, so the generalised diagonalisation $AV = BVD$ happened to be a simultaneous diagonalization as well: $AV = VD_1$ and $BV = VD_2$.

Comment: @MassimoFrittelli Uh, that looks like an oddly specific problem, since in that case $B=\alpha A + \beta I$ for suitable $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Then you know that there is a closed-form solution to that problem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Eigenvalues ? The eigenvectors have a [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors_of_the_second_derivative) as well.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Thank you, this is a life changer. Yes, as you noted, my eigenvector problem oddly recalls discrete Laplacians...

Comment: Happy to be of help @MassimoFrittelli !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments: OP mentions that his matrices are Toeplitz tridiagonal; in particular, they can all be written as $\alpha L + \beta I$, where $L$ is the finite-difference matrix `tridiag(-1,2,-1)`.

So the problem has a closed-form solution: the eigenvalues of $L$ are given by $\lambda_k = 2(1-\cos \frac{k\pi}{n+1})$, and its eigenvectors are $(v_k)_j = \sin \frac{jk\pi}{n+1}$. (From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Eigenvalues and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors_of_the_second_derivative#Pure_Dirichlet_boundary_conditions_2 ).

Comment: Thank you. A remarkable consequence of your answer is that all symmetric Toeplitz triadiagonal matrices of given dimension share the same eigenvectors. After all, the set of such matrices is a vector space of dimension just two.

Comment: is there a similar result for the case of higher order discrete Laplacians? I am happy to open a separate question if that is the case.